# I have created a database in laravel and i cant find it on wamp server(php myadmin)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migrate

While installing Laravel 5.4

I have given `crm_assignment` as my database  name but when i check it in my phpMyAdmin, i am not able to find it even after using php artisan migrate the error is " unknown database " but i could create tables and while configuring the database i found this issue.

Comment: How do you config your phpMyAdmin?

Comment: i've created tables but not able to find my database name in www folder  This error is after using "php artsian migrate" command

Comment: Have you even setup the database on wamp? Within the wamp controller there is a phpMyAdmin button...

Comment: You wont find the database within the www folder... I'd suggest dloading a program called Heidisql and connecting in via that if you're unfamiliar with PMA.

Comment: is your db visible in phpMyAdmin ? (run `show DATABASES like 'crm_assignment'` to check).
Then, check you laravel `.env` if you have the right db name and port for mysql, should be like this: 
```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=crm_assignment
```

Comment: thanks it was helpfull